# How can I diagnose a WSAECONNREFUSED error on Windows CE?

Tags: windows-mobile, tcp, windows-ce

I have a Dell Axim Windows CE device (Windows Mobile 5.0 OS 5.1.1702 Build 14366.1.0.1) connected to a Dell Latitude E6500 laptop. My C++ application is running on the CE device and listening for TCP connections on port 80. The program tries to connect to itself using the address 169.254.2.1:80, and gets error code WSAECONNREFUSED (10061). This generally indicates that nobody is listening on that port. If I change the address to 127.0.0.1:80, the connection succeeds.

Here's the weird part. If I disconnect the device from that laptop and connect it to a Dell Latitude D830, everything works properly. The 169.254.2.1 address is the same, but connecting to it succeeds. Note that this is the application running on the CE device *connecting to itself*, not connecting to the laptop, nor is it the laptop connecting to the application on the device. We have confirmed this with a few different machines - all of the E6500's show the problem, nothing else does.

I don't understand how which machine the device is connected to affects internal TCP connections. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I have to ask why you're using 169.254.2.1 to connect to yourself.  That IP address is an ActiveSync-assigned address, and it's not guaranteed to be static (it actually did change once in the past, when the driver went from USB serial to RNDIS) so using it is risky.

If you want to address yourself, use a standard loopback address like 127.0.0.1.  If you want to address an activesync partner, resolve the host name `ppp_peer` and let that give you the actual address.

My guess as to the source of the behavior is that when you connect to the PC, a local "LAN" is built with two nodes (the device and the PC).  That LAN tends to not be a "full" network (for example ICMP packets don't get transmitted) and it's probably dependent on the driver loaded by the host PC.  That's purely speculation, of course.

As I said, I'd like to know more about why you're using the address you are to see if we can "fix" the issue by doing something that's altogether a bit safer.

Comment: I'm actually not the CE guy, I'm the network guy but I don't know much about CE networking. I will look into why we're not using 127.0.0.1. Thanks

Comment: Apparently we had problems a while ago using 127.0.0.1 but the 169 address always worked so we used that. Before we change to using 127.0.0.1, they'd like to know why 169 is wrong.

Comment: Again, the 169.x address is assigned by the ActiveSync/WMDC virtual network.  It only exists when you are connected to a PC and there's no guarantee it won't change.  Hard-coding the address is not a good idea for that reason alone.  I'd personally be inclined to use `localhost` or something like `gethostname` and `gethostbyname` to resolve my actual local address.